# How to display only the text in datalist and not the value?

Tags: javascript, html, lit-element, html-datalist

Let suppose that we have the following datalist, and a js variable `var carID = ''`:

```
<input list="options" @change='${carID = e.target.value}'>
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="ID_1">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="ID_2">Lamborghini</option>
  <option value="ID_3">Jeep</option>
</datalist>
```

I'd like to show ONLY the car names in my options, and NOT the option values (that are the IDs of the cars), and have the ID of the selected car (the value of the selected option) stored in the variable, not the car name.

I tried different solutions, I post 2 of them (one totally wrong and one right but not complete, **I 've found this one in other stack overflow questions**):

1. wrong: it simply doesn't work, e.target.carID is ''.

> ```
> <input list="options" @change="${carID = e.target.carID}">
> <datalist id="options">
>   <option carID="ID_1" value="Ferrari"></option>
>   <option carID="ID_2" value="Lamborghini"></option>
>   <option carID="ID_3" value="Jeep"></option>
> </datalist>
> ```

2. Ok it's working, but what if I have 2 cars with the same name and different id? Yes, the second car is ignored and if I select the 2nd car I store the 1st car's ID.

   ```
   <input id='inputID' list="options" @change='${this.getValue}'>
    <datalist id="options">
      <option data-value="ID_1" value="Ferrari"></option>
      <option data-value="ID_2" value="Lamborghini"></option>
      <option data-value="ID_3" value="Jeep"></option>
      <option data-value="ID_4" value="Jeep"></option>
    </datalist>
   ```

js:

```
getValue(){
 let shownValue = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('inputID').value;
 let rightValue = 
   this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#options[value='"+shownValue+"']").dataset.value;
 carID = rightValue;
}
```

I cannot use JQuery. Do you have any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code `@change='${carID = e.target.carID}'` cannot work, as the right hand side of the [event handler binding](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#add-event-listeners) is not callable. You need to wrap it inside an anonymous function, e.g. like so: `@change=${(e) => { this.carID = e.target.value }}`

That being said, this is what I understood you want to do:

1. Have a list, where the user can choose from.
2. In the list, only display the name of the car, not the ID.
3. Store the selected car's ID in `carID`, not the name.

I see two ways to do that.

#### Option 1: Use `<select>`

If the list of cars is fixed, I think you will be best served using a `<select height="1">` element, resulting in a drop down box. Including the little event handler, it looks something like this:

```html
<select @change=${(e) => { this.carID = e.target.value }}>
  <option value="ID_1">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="ID_2">Lamborghini</option>
  <option value="ID_3">Jeep</option>
  <option value="ID_4">Jeep</option>
</select>
```

This will display the text from the text content of the `<option>` elements, but set the `value` of the `<select>` from the `<option>`'s `value` attribute, and by the virtue of the onchange event handler will set the `carID` field on the element.

You can even have two cars with different IDs, but the same name. Note however, that your users would not know, if the display text is the same, which of the two "Jeep" entries to choose. So that might not be a good idea (but I don't know your full use case).

#### Option 2: Use `<input>` with `<datalist>`

Now, if the list of cars is not fixed, i.e. the users are allowed to enter arbitrary data and the selection list is not for limiting their choices, but to help them (prevent typos, speed-up entry) you can use an `<input>` with an associated `<datalist>`. But the popup will display both, the `<option>`'s value and text content (if they are both defined and different). If you insist on only showing the name of the car, not the ID, then the name has to go in the `value` attribute of the `<option>` (or the text content). While you could put the ID in the dataset, you really don't need to.

In any case you'll need to map the value string back to the ID through your own code. This will only work if "cars and names" is a one-to-one (aka bijective) mapping, so no two cars with the exact same name would be allowed. (Otherwise your code cannot know which one has been selected just by looking at the name.)

```js
const CARS_BY_ID = {
  ID_1: 'Ferrari',
  ID_2: 'Lamborghini',
  ID_3: 'Jeep',
}

class MyElem extends LitElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.carID = null;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <input list="myopts" @change=${this.carChanged}>
      <datalist id="myopts">
        ${Object.values(CARS_BY_ID).map((name) => html`<option>${name}</option>`)}
      </datalist>`;
  }

  carChanged(e) {
    const name = e.target.value;
    this.carID = null;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(CARS_BY_ID)) {
      if (value === name) {
        this.carID = key;
      }
    }
    console.log(`this.carID = ${this.carID}`);
  }
}
```

Note, that in this example the user can e.g. enter "Bugatti" and `this.carID` will be `null`.

Also note, that `this.carID` has not been registered as a lit-element property (it's not listed in `static get properties`), so there will be no update lifecycle triggered, and no re-rendering happens upon that change.